# DartDoc generation not working when importing package inside library

Tags: documentation, dart, dart-editor

I'm trying to generate the documentation of dart code.
I've noticed that I cannot generate any documentation through DartDoc because inside my library I sometime need to import some external libraries.

Below I have a small example that shows my actual problem.

**listController.dart**

```dart
part of controllers;

@NgController (
    selector: '[list-control]',
    publishAs: 'listCtrl'
)
class ListController {

}
```

**controllers.dart**

```dart
library controllers;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

part 'listController.dart';
```

**The end result on the console**

```
Running dartdoc...
Using snapshot /Users/ecomtemarois/Downloads/dart/dart-sdk/bin/snapshots/utils_wrapper.dart.snapshot
Analyzing libraries...
../../../Documents/ecash.dart/ecash/controllers/controllers.dart:3:8: Error: Can't read 'package:angular/angular.dart' (Error reading 'packages/angular/angular.dart' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)).
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/ecash.dart/ecash/controllers/listController.dart:3:2: Error: Cannot resolve 'NgController'.
@NgController (
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Documents/ecash.dart/ecash/controllers/listController.dart:3:1: Error: Not a compile-time constant.
@NgController (
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: generation failed: Bad state: Failed to create mirror system.
StackTrace: #0      analyze.<anonymous closure> (file:///Volumes/data/b/build/slave/dart-editor-mac-trunk/build/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/compiler/implementation/mirrors/dart2js_mirror.dart:232)
#1      _Future._propagateToListeners.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:457)
#2      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:720)
#3      _RootZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:862)
#4      _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:449)
#5      _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:302)
#6      Future.forEach.nextElement (dart:async/future.dart:269)
#7      _Future._propagateToListeners.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:457)
#8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:720)
#9      _RootZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:862)
#10     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:449)
#11     _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:302)
#12     Future.forEach.nextElement (dart:async/future.dart:269)
#13     _Future._propagateToListeners.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:457)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:720)
#15     _RootZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:862)
#16     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:449)
#17     _Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:302)
#18     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:358)
#19     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:18)
#20     _createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:11)
#21     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (timer_impl.dart:151)
#22     _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (timer_impl.dart:166)
#23     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:93)
```

I would like to know how to be able to have access on those package and still be able to generate the documentation.

thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug, how about filling a bug at http://dartbug.com ?

Comment: @Fox32: This not only looks like a bug. This is a real bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `packages` directory next your dart file. If you're using [Pub](http://pub.dartlang.org) this directory should be created with a `pub get` command. If you don't, you can provide the path of your *packages* with `--package-root=<path>` option.

NB: looking at your path (`../../../Documents/ecash.dart/ecash/controllers/listController.dart`) you don't seem to follow the [Package layout conventions](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html). I would recommand to follow it.